# How does one calculate Mean Squared Error for a multivarite linear regression using Accord.NET?

Tags: machine-learning, f#, regression, accord.net

The book `Mastering .NET Machine Learning` by `Jamie Dixon` has some code implementing multivariate linear regression. Using this data:

```
let xs = [| [|15.0;130.0|];[|18.0;127.0|];[|15.0;128.0|];[|17.0;120.0|];[|16.0;115.0|] |]
let y = [|3.6;3.5;3.8;3.4;2.6|]
```

the following statistics are calculated in the book:

```
val sse : float = 0.1734125099 // Sum of Squared Errors
val mse : float = 0.03468250198 // Mean Squared Error
val rmse : float = 0.186232387 // Root Mean Squared Error
val r2 : float = 0.7955041157 // Coefficient of Determination or R-Squared
```

The code in the book uses `version 3.0.2` of `Accord.NET`.

Under the latest version (`3.8.0`) the code in the book does not work. The following works under this latest version:

```
open Accord.Statistics.Models.Regression.Linear
let ols = OrdinaryLeastSquares()
let regression = ols.Learn(xs, y)
let stderr = regression.GetStandardError(xs, y)
```

The book shows a way to calculate `sse`, `mse`, and `rmse` but with the current API I could not find a way to calculate those statistics.

Can someone suggest a way to calculate one of `sse`, `mse`, or `rmse` using the API of `version 3.8.0`? These three statistics are related by simple formulas so it is enough to calculate one of them. I found a formula that relates one of them to the value obtained by calling `GetStandardError` but the formula is not intuitive to me, it is just an ad hoc relation.

BTW, I know how to calculate the three statistics using simple formulas, I just want to know how they relate to the `standard error` and other statistics returned by the API functions, and also to save some execution time by not calculating them with my own code.